# Ext3 Stride/Stripe-Width Calculation for 3-Disk Software RAID1E

Tags: linux, raid, ext3

For reasons too complex to get into here, I'm using a 3-disk RAID1E on some linux systems.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#Linux_MD_RAID_10) for more info on that.

So my understanding is that for optimizing filesystem layout on this volume, you use the following calculation:

```
chunk-size = 64kB
block-size = 4kB
stride = chunk / block = 16
stripe-width = stride * ( (numdisks)/2 ) = 16 * 1.5 = 24
```

However, mkfs.ext3 gives a warning when I use that calculation for setting the stripe-width, that it should be a power of two.

So my question is, am I doing it right?  Should I be treating it like a standard four-disk RAID10, since the stripes are of the same size?

Update: it's not a degraded array, it's a fully supported configuration.  Read the link from the first paragraph.

Comment: 3 disk...RAID 10? You mean you're running an intentionally degraded array?

Comment: If you had the correct number of drives in your array then it would work out correctly.

Comment: @MDMarra - no, it's not degraded - linux md supports 3-disk RAID10 where each stripe is mirrored across two disks, per the link in the first paragraph.

Comment: So you have a RAID 1E, then.

Comment: It appears that Linux MD is lying to you. What you have is a R1E. The calculations you have is for an R10 which requires an even number of disks.

Comment: Can you point me to stripe-width formula for RAID1E then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran some experiments using XFS instead of ext3 on various size and levels of MD RAID.  It seems like the following formula applies across the board:

```
# chunk is specified in mdadm create, block in mkfs
stride = chunk / block
stripe-width = ((slices - parity) * stride
```

Where parity is zero for RAID0/10/1E, one for RAID5, two for RAID6.

So in the case of my original question, stripe-width should be set to **48** (64kB chunk, 4kB block, 3 slices, zero parity).  When I use these settings, mkfs.ext3 no longer gives a warning about stripe-width not being divisible by the stride.

Answer (score 2):

Setting your stripe width higher than 64kB will be suboptimal.

Any write of a size higher than 64kB will result in 4 writes - one write to one disk, one write to another, and two writes to one.

Just set your stripe width to 64kB.

Comment: Why?  What's actually happening with the disk stripes and writes that makes this the case?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your optimisation from the wrong place. You need to start from the I/O size you are optimising for (e.g. block size that your application does reads/writes in), and optimise the whole stack for that. I wrote an article on this exact subject that explains why [storage stack and file system alignment is important](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/08/18/mysql-mariadb-innodb-on-non-zfs/), which you may find helpful.