# RAID configuration HPE Proliant DL360 G6

Tags: raid, hyper-v, hpe

I've got an old server and I would like some advice on the RAID configuration. I have 8 disks of 300GB.
And I'm not sure which setup is more desirable.

- 2x RAID1 (os: hyper-V)
- 6x RAID5 (VMs)

or

- 8x RAID5

  - If I choose for 8x RAID5, will the host OS see it as one disk or can that be changed in the Array Controller?
  - Is partitioning in the host OS desirable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend you using RAID5. The following thread describes it. 
[RAID with three disks (RAID 5 vs RAID 1E)](https://serverfault.com/questions/753246/raid-with-three-disks-raid-5-vs-raid-1e)
In addition, assuming your drives are HDDs, you will get low random write performance, which can be critical for VMs. I would recommend you going RAID10 for your VMs it will give you decent performance.